# SQL Server + 'Merging results'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am 2 result sets from the below query which I want to 'combine' the results into 1 single table but not sure how to proceed from here, can someone please kindly provide some guidance:

```
SELECT userid, vehicleId, count(vehicleId) As SearchCount FROM MemberSearches 
GROUP BY userid, vehicleId 
ORDER BY count(vehicleId) DESC

SELECT f.UserId, v.AutoId AS VehicleId, count(v.AutoId) AS SearchCount FROM Favorites f
LEFT JOIN [SellPost] sp
ON (f.PostId = sp.AutoId)
LEFT JOIN [Vehicle] v
ON (sp.CarId = v.AutoId)
GROUP BY f.UserId, v.AutoId
ORDER BY COUNT(v.AutoId) DESC
```

**Result from the first select:**

```
UserId       VehicleId  SearchCount
2926FC8A78FB    7       3
2926FC8A78FB    2       2
2926FC8A78FB    6       1
```

**Result from the second select:**

```
UserId       VehicleId  SearchCount
2926FC8A78FB    1       5
2926FC8A78FB    2       5
```

**I need to achieve the final result as:**

```
UserId       VehicleId  SearchCount
2926FC8A78FB    1       5
2926FC8A78FB    2       7
2926FC8A78FB    6       1
2926FC8A78FB    7       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not efficient, just test its working...

```
   SELECT userid, vehicleId, SUM(SearchCount) As SearchCount
FROM
(SELECT userid, vehicleId, count(vehicleId) As SearchCount FROM MemberSearches 
GROUP BY userid, vehicleId 
UNION ALL
SELECT f.UserId, v.AutoId AS VehicleId, count(v.AutoId) AS SearchCount FROM Favorites f
LEFT JOIN [SellPost] sp
ON (f.PostId = sp.AutoId)
LEFT JOIN [Vehicle] v
ON (sp.CarId = v.AutoId)
GROUP BY f.UserId, v.AutoId
) t
GROUP BY userid, vehicleId
```

Comment: @user415795 Is this answer giving you the expected result?

Comment: Thanks guys, this actually yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    userid, vehicleId, count(*) As SearchCount
FROM (
    SELECT userid, vehicleId FROM MemberSearches 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.UserId, v.AutoId FROM Favorites f
    LEFT JOIN [SellPost] sp
    ON (f.PostId = sp.AutoId)
    LEFT JOIN [Vehicle] v
    ON (sp.CarId = v.AutoId)
) AS X
GROUP BY userid, vehicleId 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a `UNION` here; consider **vehicleid** *2*, where the desired result is the total of the rows in each subquery.

You can join the two results together:

```
SELECT t1.userid, t2.vehicleId, SearchCount = t1.SearchCount + t2.SearchCount
FROM 
(
  SELECT userid, vehicleId, count(vehicleId) As SearchCount FROM MemberSearches 
  GROUP BY userid, vehicleId
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT f.UserId, v.AutoId AS VehicleId, count(v.AutoId) AS SearchCount FROM Favorites f
  LEFT JOIN [SellPost] sp
  ON (f.PostId = sp.AutoId)
  LEFT JOIN [Vehicle] v
  ON (sp.CarId = v.AutoId)
  GROUP BY f.UserId, v.AutoId
) t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.vehicleid = t2.vehicleid
ORDER BY userid, vehicleid
```

Depending on the data, you may need to use a `LEFT` or `FULL` join here.

Or user @Serge has another alternative.